# Testing REST API and rendering with EJS

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, ejs

Consider this scenario:

When you visit my `/` page the server will respond with a JSON like the following

```
res.json({
    message: 'Welcome home.'
});
```

to test this, I create a file **home.test.js** and test it like so:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../server')

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('GET /', () => {
    it('should respond with homepage', (done) => {
        chai
            .request(server)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                expect(res.body.message).to.equal('Welcome home.');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

The simple test passes and everything is going as planned. Here is the problem. Later on, when I want to use **ejs to render the view** my code is going to change to this:

```
 res.render('index', { message: 'Welcome home.' });
```

So now my previous test will not pass as `res.body.message` will now have the value `undefined`. How can I actually test this now that the response will be `res.render()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can affect the message to the request body before rendering the page. Your code will be something like this:

```
 res.body.message="Welcome home".
 res.render('index',{message:"welcome home"})
```